# One Page Checkout Not Working in Magento ver. 1.7.0.2

Tags: javascript, magento, checkout, magento-1.7

One Page Checkout screen appears but never given the option for login or checkout as guest. When i am running checkout page in IE its showing some java-script errors. Here i am attaching the screenshots 
[SCREENSHOT1](http://i49.tinypic.com/906f4z.jpg)

[SCREENSHOT2](http://i46.tinypic.com/15e92ky.jpg)

[SCREENSHOT3](http://i45.tinypic.com/11s2l43.jpg)

Any one please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your "bieber...." field really exists? As far as I see you've a label, but no input : this will be a problem :)